# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Erro

Tags: php

I have this code in a PHP File

```
$file = file_get_contents($url);
```

running on PHP Version 5.2.17

Error message is:

```
 failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Complete code:

```
<?php 
Header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
/*
 * in JavaScript call with `encodeURIComponent`
 * $.get('proxy.php?proxy_url='+encodeURIComponent('http://google.com?param=1&param2=2'))
 */ 



error_reporting(~0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);




$url = rawurldecode($_GET['proxy_url']);
$cb = ! empty($_GET['callback']) ? $_GET['callback'] : null;

if(preg_match('#xxx\.xxx\.com/xxx/#', $url)){
    $url = preg_replace('#http\://xxx\.xxx\.com/xxx/#', '', $url);
}

if(! preg_match('#^https?:#', $url)){
    $url = preg_replace('#^[\.\/]+#', '', $url);

    if(!file_exists($url)){
        echo 'File not found';
        die(0);
    }
}

if(preg_match('#\.xml$#', $url)){
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
}

$file = file_get_contents($url);

if($cb){
    header('Content-type: application/javascript');
    echo $cb.'('.$file.');';

}else{
    echo $file;
}
```

Comment: Please post `$url` in your question.

Comment: Add the entire script, please let me know your toughs... thanks!

Comment: `$url` is probably invalid and causing an error on the server. Validate `$url` before using it.

Comment: could you post an example

Comment: _“Any idea what could be wrong?”_ – You’d have to ask the admin of the remote server that question – only he can look into the error logs and determine why his server refuses your request.

Comment: I have posted here the errors from PHP file. May I provide other information?